# what does re.compile() and remove_tags() mean in the below code?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, python-re

In the below data preprocessing code, I know re.compile() is used to convert into a regex object. But what happens in remove_tags()? What kind of pattern is being removed here? I couldn't figure out the regular expression mentioned in re.compile() stored in TAG.RE variable.

```
TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
def remove_tags(text):
return TAG_RE.sub('', text)
```

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.)

Answer (score 0):

- [] -> Represents any single character within the brackets
  eg; h[oa]t finds hot and hat, but not hit
- ^  -> Represents any character not in the brackets
  eg; h[^oa]t finds hit, but not hot and hat
- '+' -> Represents one or more characters.
  It is a quantifier which is used to specify the no of occurrences to match. eg; a+ represent At least one a

Coming to question:-

- [^>]  -> Represents any single character except '>'
- [^>]+ -> Represents any single character except '>' one or more no of times.
- <[^>]+> -> Match a pattern that starts with < after that various no of character occur except > and then ends with >

```
# remove html tags using RegEx
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'<[^>]+') # tags look like <....>
result = pattern.sub('',text)   # replace them with blank
```